# AWS lambda, get used bandwidth on execution

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I'm looking to get the bandwidth used for each lambda execution. Do you know a way to do that?

I'm building a hot-code gateway and need to meter the bandwidth consumption.

Comment: This is indeed a conundrum. So this is a long shot but I wonder if you could devise a way to use lambda in a vpc, turn on flow logs to get byte count for the ENIs that lambda attaches to, and at the same time log the calling customer to in your function cloudwatch. Then someone cross-reference. Like I said it's a long-shot. http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonVPC/latest/UserGuide/flow-logs.html#flow-logs-records-examples

Answer (score 0):

Try tagging your functions by customer.

https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2017/04/aws-lambda-supports-tagging-and-cost-allocations/

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/tagging.html

This may cause you to have to duplicate functions for customers, but that could also be a good thing because you can use per function concurrency limits to keep one customer from using up your regional concurrency limit (which would throttle the rest of your customers).

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/limits.html